# runtime.SetFinalizer: could not determine kind of name for C.Char

Tags: go

Please consider this sample go code below:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"


import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // Convert Go string to C string using C.CString
    cString := C.CString("Wold!")
    fmt.Printf("C.CString type: %T\n", cString)
    //C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cString)) // <-- this works, but I don't want to free it manually..

    runtime.SetFinalizer(&cString, func(t *C.Char) {
        C.free(unsafe.Pointer(t))
    })
}
```

I am experimenting with cGo, and trying to free `cString`. When I try to free my variable cString using `runtime.SetFinalizer` I encounter:

```
$ go build a.go 
# command-line-arguments
./a.go:22:41: could not determine kind of name for C.Char
```

Please point me the correct direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cgo system is turning your wrapper into something the Go compiler understands, it has to translate each of the C types to a Go type for various purposes.  It turns out this doesn't work for your case (this is the error you saw).

That's actually OK, because your code would never have worked the way you wanted in the first place.  A runtime finalizer runs when Go's garbage collector is ready to release a Go object that occupies Go memory, but `C.Cstring` returns a pointer that is *not* Go memory.  In particular, note the following quote from [the cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> ```
> // Go string to C string
> // The C string is allocated in the C heap using malloc.
> // It is the caller's responsibility to arrange for it to be
> // freed, such as by calling C.free (be sure to include stdlib.h
> // if C.free is needed).
> func C.CString(string) *C.char
> ```

Since the returned string is on the "C heap" it will never be finalized by the Go garbage collector.  Had your code compiled, it would have just been a no-op.

If you have a Go object whose lifetime parallels that of the C object, you could perhaps use that.  Here's a made-up (but working) example:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
*/
import "C"

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "time"
        "unsafe"
)

type S struct {
        Foo    int
        ToFree unsafe.Pointer
}

func main() {
        doit()
        runtime.GC()
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond) // ugly hack
}

func doit() {
        cString := C.CString("Wold!")
        fmt.Printf("C.CString type: %T\n", cString)
        x := &S{Foo: 1, ToFree: unsafe.Pointer(cString)}
        runtime.SetFinalizer(x, func(t *S) {
                fmt.Println("freeing C string")
                C.free(t.ToFree)
        })
}
```

When the allocated object for `x` goes out of scope it becomes eligible for GC.  The actual GC may never happen, so I forced one with `runtime.GC()` in `main`.  This triggers the finalizer:

```
$ ./cfree_example
C.CString type: *main._Ctype_char
freeing C string
```

The "ugly hack" is in there because if `main` returns before the finalizer call has finished writing the `freeing C string` messages, it gets lost.  In a real program you would not need this.